# Display ajax result into html

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to display json array element into the script below

Comment: Could you post the JSON string here? There's no need for using a third party website.

Comment: JSON data in meant to be interpreted as an object/array etc. How do you want to format the data within it as HTML? It is not HTML itself.

Comment: how can i display photo from the json array to img src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Loop through JSON in data and output images using its URLs
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
     var imgEl = "<img src='" + data[i].photo + "' />";
     $('#wowslider-container').append(imgEl);
   }
```